# Issue creating a Menu in an independent file

Tags: html, menu

I would like to have a Menu that I could have in a separate file so I could call and use in multiple pages and if I need to modify the menu I have to modify only in one place.

This is what I've done.

I create a HTML file (this will be any of the pages calling the Menu)

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="TopMenu.html">   </iframe> 

This is the main site. I can have any page / content here

</body>
</html>
```

The page above is calling the file TopMenu.hmtl where I have my code for the Menu. Code below:

```
<html>

<style>

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #FF9900;
    color: white;
}
</style>

 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a class="active" href="www.Myweb/Home.html">Home</a>
<a href="www.Myweb/ContactUs.html">Contact</a>
<a href="www.Myweb/about">About</a>
</div>

</html>
```

Questions:
1.  I see the code as in image (1) below and I would like to see the menu bar as covering the whole width of the page (from left to right)

[image]

2. When I click in one of the links in the menu, I see the new page as below, (like inside of the Menu box), instead I would like to see a new completely page

[image]

Thank you very much for help

Comment: Don’t use (i)frames for that, that has many drawbacks. Use a server-side technique that can _include_ files.

Comment: But regarding your specific questions, if you really want to follow this bad approach: 1) You need to specify the width for the iframe. 2) Your links inside the iframe need the `target` attribute set, so that they link “outside” of the iframe. `_top` is most likely the value you want.